# Test Flask Dance with unittest

Tags: python, flask, oauth, python-unittest

I have written a flask application that uses flask dance for user authentication. Now I want to test a few views for that I have enabled `@login_required`.

I wanted to follow the flask dance testing [docs](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html) but I could not get it to work. Because I am only using unittest and not pytest. I also use github and not google as in the docs. So is `sess['github_oauth_token']` correct? A prototype sample test could look like the following:

```
def test_sample(self):
    with self.client as client:
        with client.session_transaction() as sess:
            sess['github_oauth_token'] = {
                'access_token': 'fake access token',
                'id_token': 'fake id token',
                'token_type': 'Bearer',
                'expires_in': '3600',
                'expires_at': self.time + 3600
            }

        response = client.post(url_for('core.get_sample'), data=self.fake_sample)

        self.assertRedirects(response, url_for('core.get_sample'))
```

The assertRedirect fails because I am redirected to the login page `http://localhost/login/github?next=%2Fsample%2F` and not `url_for('core.get_sample')`.

Then tried to simply disable it, by following the official flask login [docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#protecting-views).

> It can be convenient to globally turn off authentication when unit
>   testing. To enable this, if the application configuration variable
>   LOGIN_DISABLED is set to True, this decorator will be ignored.

<strike>But this does not work as well, the test still fail because login_required is somehow executed.</strike>

So my questions are:

- Because I am using github and not google as in the docs is `github_oauth_token` the correct key for the session?
- How do I test views that have the `@login_required` decorator with unittest when using Flask Dance?

Edit: `LOGIN_DISABLED=True` works as long as I define it in my config class I use for `app.config.from_object(config['testing'])`, what did not work was to set `self.app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = True` in my setup method.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're using the `unittest` framework for testing instead of `pytest`, you can still use the mock storage classes documented in [the Flask-Dance testing documentation](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html). You'll just need to use some other mechanism to replace the real storage with the mock, instead of the `monkeypatch` fixture from Pytest. You can easily use the [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html) package instead, like this:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from flask_dance.consumer.storage import MemoryStorage
from my_app import create_app

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def test_sample(self):
        github_bp = self.app.blueprints["github"]
        storage = MemoryStorage({"access_token": "fake-token"})
        with patch.object(github_bp, "storage", storage):
            with self.client as client:
                response = client.post(url_for('core.get_sample'), data=self.fake_sample)

        self.assertRedirects(response, url_for('core.get_sample'))
```

This example uses the [application factory pattern](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/), but you could also import your `app` object from somewhere else and use it that way, if you want.